# Create UILabel with for loop by characters from database

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop, swift3, uilabel

I'm creating UILabe using For loop by characters from SQLite database, how can I do that?

This my code:

```
for data in listdata {
    for tar in [data.ans.characters] as NSArray {
        var counter = ""
        counter = tar as! String
        let targetLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: xAxis, y: yAxis, width: 50, height: 50))
        targetLabel.backgroundColor = .white
        targetLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
        targetLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        targetLabel.text = counter
        targetLabel.textAlignment = .center
        self.view.addSubview(targetLabel)
    }
}
```

`data.ans` is string data and I convert to characters array and it's derived from `listdata`, when I type the previous code get me crash! and his massage is:

> Could not cast value of type 'Swift.String.CharacterView'

And when edit my code to:

```
for data in listdata {
    for tar in AnyObject[data.ans.characters] as NSArray { // Instance member 'subscript' cannot be used on type 'AnyObject'
        var counter = ""
        counter = tar as String
        let targetLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: xAxis, y: yAxis, width: 50, height: 50))
        targetLabel.backgroundColor = .white
        targetLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
        targetLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        targetLabel.text = counter
        targetLabel.textAlignment = .center
        self.view.addSubview(targetLabel)
    }
}
```

Get me error massage:

> Instance member 'subscript' cannot be used on type 'AnyObject'

What's solve? And how can I loop UILabel on the number of characters from SQLite database?

I want create like this in picture but from SQLite database `(data.ans)`:

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to create a `UILabel` for each character in `data.ans`? Or are you trying to create a `UILabel` for each `data.ans`?

Comment: Look my post after editing @DavidCullen

Comment: `for tar in data.ans.characters` should give you what you want.

Comment: I want like that in picture @DavidCullen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `characters` property is already iterable. You have two other problems:

1. You need to convert `tar` to a `String` to assign it to the `.text` property
2. You need to add the `width` plus some delta to `x` for each iteration

**Code**

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 345, height: 70))

class Data {
    var ans = "LONDON"
}
var data = Data()
var x = 10
var y = 10
for tar in data.ans.characters {
    let targetLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: 50, height: 50))
    x += 50 + 5
    targetLabel.backgroundColor = .white
    targetLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
    targetLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    targetLabel.text = String(tar)
    targetLabel.textAlignment = .center
    view.addSubview(targetLabel)
    let xString = String(format: "%\(03)d", x)
    print("x = \(xString), tar = \(tar)")
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

This was run in a Swift playground.

[image: LONDON]

Select View -> Assistant Editor -> Show Assistant Editor from the menu to see the `UIView`.

**Output**

```
x =  65, tar = L
x = 120, tar = O
x = 175, tar = N
x = 230, tar = D
x = 285, tar = O
x = 340, tar = N
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
for tar in [data.ans.characters] as NSArray {
```

to this

```
for tar in listdata {
```

Comment: I can't do that because I have database has two rows (ques and ans) I want specific just ans and convert from string to characters @Saurabh

Comment: Can you please explain more .

Comment: Looking now my post @Saurabh